# How can i dynamically include another VF page in a tab.

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, visualforce-component

I have created dynamic tabs using following code -

```
public Component.Apex.TabPanel getMyTabs()
{
    Component.Apex.TabPanel myTabPanel = new Component.Apex.TabPanel();  
     for (integer i=0 ;i<menus.size();i++)  //just a sample, this could easily be a SOQL loop
     {
         Component.Apex.Tab myTab = new Component.Apex.Tab();
         myTab.Label = menus.get(i).name;
         myTab.name =  menus.get(i).name;
         myTab.switchtype = 'client';
         //Want to associate a VF page with this Tab so that if someone Click this tab  
         associated VF page content render in body part.
         myTab.style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;  background-image: url(/dimg/portalTabActiveRight000099C2E4FE.gif)';
         myTabPanel.childComponents.add(myTab);
     }   
    return myTabPanel;
}
```

I Want to associate a particular VF page with each Tab so that if someone Click that tab
             associated VF page content render in the body part.

menus list also contains target VF page related path which will be displayed when user clicks in respective tab.

I am not getting anything how to do this. Can someone help me plz

Comment: Developers and ISVs please vote for this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kteEAAQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did u try using `<apex:iframe src="Vf_page">` in the page and embed the vf

Comment: I tried -              Component.Apex.Iframe iframe = new Component.Apex.Iframe();
             iframe.src = '/apex/HelloWord';
             myTab.childComponents.add(iframe);

Comment: But Not working

Comment: wht happend when you tried ifram is the section not rendering still??

Comment: Its working now.. my mistake. Can i not use apex:include instead of Component.Apex.Iframe?

Comment: i have never tried using include but from this doc looks like you can http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_templates_include.htm

Comment: i found iframe more handy since it helps embedding external urls too

Comment: Actually when i write Component.Apex.Include incl= new Component.Apex.Include();// It gives me an error that no include component found.

Comment: FROM THE DOCS : Search for Dynamic Visualforce Restrictions and this is what I found.<br/>Not every feature of Visualforce makes sense in a dynamic context, so some components are not available dynamically. This section describes some limitations of dynamic Visualforce components.
The following standard Visualforce components don’t have corresponding dynamic representations in Apex:
<apex:attribute>
<apex:component>
<apex:componentBody>
<apex:composition>
<apex:define>
<apex:dynamicComponent>
<apex:include>
<apex:insert>
<apex:param>
<apex:variable>

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy... I am facing one more issue i am not able to override tabs CSS. If i do something like this - myTab.style='font-size: 150px;'; it doesn't effect my tab font size. not only font other css are also not working with tab

Comment: I do my styling in the page like this <apex:tabpanel tabClass= "activetab"/> <style> .activetab{font-size:20px;}</style> probably using the tabstyle property in your component.apex.tabpanel could solve the CSS issue

Comment: i have tried this tab and tabpanel style property but didn't work. I think it is taking standard tab styling but i am not able to find the way to disable this standard styling.

Comment: i have tabstyle set in my page it works fine, not sure how you would be able to define style attri in the controller :! @eyescream do you have any idea!!

Comment: wait did you try tabclass  property not the style property its called "tabclass" not style !!!

Comment: not yet. i have to write .css file for that as i am working in apex class and then extract that using static resource. it will take some time

Comment: ah i am sure the tabstyle should work i worked on it today :) and changed the color of tabs using css

Comment: Did you do that in Apex class ? I am doing this in apex class like this -  Component.Apex.Tab myTab = new Component.Apex.Tab();
             myTab.Label = menus.get(i).name;
             myTab.name =  menus.get(i).name;
             myTab.switchtype = 'client';            
             myTab.style='font-size: 150px;';             
             myTabPanel.childComponents.add(myTab); but it is not changing tab font size.

Comment: try mytab.tabclass=css_from_staticresource

Comment: trying to do the same. Finding out how can i access static resource .css in apex class

Comment: Did you figure out how to if not check this : http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2012/05/static-resource-url-in-apex.html

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. I would like to tell you one thing that , the person who has written this post is working in my company :).

Comment: ah tht was funny :P

Comment: Can we assign Visual-force page at run time using apex class while Tab(My tab) already created from visualforce tab?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.calypso_latest_news}?cat=press releases">Press releases</apex:outputLink></li>
```

I think I've had the same problem before We have news section where it renders to different categories e.g. Events, press releases and I use the link above to render it. 
There is also a different thing you can do on the vf page in order to display different information, specific for different categories

```
<apex:outputText value="Product launches" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cat='product launches'}" />
<apex:outputText value="Events" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cat='events'}" />




<apex:outputText value="Find out the latest about" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cat='press releases'}" />
<apex:outputText value="Incident Updates" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cat='incident updates'}" />**
```

So if you have 3 tabs you can put

```
  <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Tab1}?cat=info1 ">Tab1</apex:outputLink></li>
  <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Tab1}?cat=info2 ">tab2</apex:outputLink></li>
  <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.Tab1}?cat=info3 ">Tab3</apex:outputLink></li>
```

And render information using

```
<apex:outputText value="Some Info Here" rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cat='info1'}" />
```